# What would be the syntax of a jquery function that should be initialised when document is ready and when document changes?

Tags: jquery, syntax, document

The background is: I got an editable table with a button that adds a new row. I also got two functions which starts with:

> $(function () {

These functions let the user edit lines and the user can also drag and drops things into that table. But it only works for the normal rows, not the recently added rows even they have the same class as all the others. Could it be that the functions has to be modified so they'll work for newly added lines too? If yes - how to do that? Or is it another problem?

Regards

Edit:
Here is my code for the button that adds a table row:

```
$(function () {
    $("#editableTable").on('click', 'input.addButton', function () {

          var nexttr = $(this).closest('tr');
          $(nexttr).next().before('\n<tr class=\"sortable-row ui-droppable\">\n<td>entry 1</td>\n<td>entry 2</td>\n<td>entry 2</td>\n<td>entry 4</td>\n<td>entry 5</td>\n<td>entry 6 </td>\n<td>entry 7</td>\n<td>entry 8</td>\n<td><input type=\'button\' class=\'addButton\' value=\'add row\' /></td>\n<td><input type=\'button\' class=\'deleteButton\' value=\'delete row\' /></td>\n</tr>\n');
          oddRowColor(); //changes color in every second row
    });
});
```

The Code that makes the td-elements editable is this:

```
$(function () {
$("td").dblclick(function () {
    var OriginalContent = $(this).text();

    $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
    $(this).html("<input type='text' id='textinput' size='100' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
    $(this).children().first().focus();

    $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var newContent = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().text(newContent);
            $(".cellEditing").removeClass("cellEditing");
        }
    });

    $(this).children().first().blur(function (e) {
        $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
        $(".cellEditing").removeClass("cellEditing");

    });
});
});
```

Comment: First: You should have the document ready handler (`$(function () {});`) just once in your page. Second: You're probably not using delegation to attach the handlers, so dynamically added elements will be ignored. Third and most important: Show us your code, so we're able to help you.

Comment: Thank you so far. I added my code above. I'll read the about the delegation method in the jquery documentary. Thx for the tip! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comments, give this solution a try. Maybe it needs some tweaking, as you didn't post your HTML markup:

```
$(function () {
    $("#editableTable").delegate('input.addButton', 'click', function () {
        var nexttr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var newtr = $('<tr />', { class: 'sortable-row ui-droppable' });

        for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
            var newtd = $('<td />').html('entry ' + i.toString());
            newtr.append($(newtd));
        }

        var newtdaddbutton = $('<td />');
        var newaddbutton = $('<button />', { class: 'addButton' }).html('add row');
        newtdaddbutton.append($(newaddbutton));
        newtr.append($(newtdaddbutton));

        var newtddelbutton = $('<td />');       
        var newdelbutton = $('<button />', { class: 'deleteButton' }).html('delete row');
        newtddelbutton.append($(newdelbutton));
        newtr.append($(newtddelbutton));

        $(nexttr).next().before($(newtr));

        oddRowColor(); //changes color in every second row
    });

    $("#editableTable").delegate('td', 'dblclick', function () {
        var OriginalContent = $(this).text();

        $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
        var textinput = $('<input />', { type: 'text', id: 'textinput', size: 100, value: OriginalContent });
        $(this).html($(textinput));
        $(this).children().first().focus();

        $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                var newContent = $(this).val();
                $(this).parent().text(newContent);
                $(".cellEditing").removeClass("cellEditing");
            }
        });

        $(this).children().first().blur(function (e) {
            $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
            $(".cellEditing").removeClass("cellEditing");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow! Awesome! It worked! Thank you so much!!! Now i'll have a closer look at it and try to edit my drag&drop function so it works with the new rows too. :)

Answer (score -1):

If you set listener on document ready, when you add new row they are not affected.

You must add listener on the row, when you click on add row.

```
//Start function on ready
$(function () {

$('.rowClass').draggable().click(function(){
//your code here
});


$('btnAdd').click(function(){
//add new row code
var newRow = $('<tr class="rowClass">');
newRow.draggable().click(function(){
//the same code here
});


});

});
```

I don't know how you make the table, but the logic is there, bye.

Comment: If the elements share the same class, the OP can attach the handler on the document ready event, using delegation. Why stick the code into multiple places? It's pointless.

Comment: I don't understand??? Why -1? Why pointless??

The problem is http://jsfiddle.net/WUYuR/

If on the click of the add new row not set listener on the new row, the new row don't have any listener.

Sorry for my bad english....

Comment: If you attach the event handler before-hand, by delegation, as the OP knows the elements will share a common class, you don't need to do it repeatedly every time you add a new one. Are you Brazilian/Portuguese? If so, I can explain in Portuguese to you.

Comment: Explain in italian :)

Comment: I'm Italiano-Brasiliano, but am still learning Italian. Parlo l'Italiano ma non molto bene. :)

Comment: You speak italian better than my english :D

Comment: Azz, good,I understood what you meant but I did not know this method, this change all of my code :D

Comment: It's really useful if you have a root element that will be always there, and you can attach the event handlers to the future ones that would be added to it.